# Acting like unsigned int overflow. What is causing it?

Tags: c++, integer, overflow, limit

I have this function which generates a specified number of so called 'triangle numbers'. If I print out the deque afterwords, the numbers increase, jumps down, then increases again. Triangle numbers should never get lower as i rises so there must be some kind of overflow happening. I tried to fix it by adding the line `if(toPush > INT_MAX) return i - 1;` to try to stop the function from generating more numbers (and return the number it generated) if the result is overflowing. That is not working however, the output continues to be incorrect (increases for a while, jumps down to a lower number, then increases again). The line I added doesn't actually seem to be doing anything at all. Return is not being reached. Does anyone know what's going on here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <climits>
int generateTriangleNumbers(std::deque<unsigned int> &triangleNumbers, unsigned int generateCount) {
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= generateCount; i++) {
         unsigned int toPush = (i * (i + 1)) / 2;
         if(toPush > INT_MAX) return i - 1;
         triangleNumbers.push_back(toPush);
    }
return generateCount;
}
```

Comment: What is the first value of i for which it doesn't work?  If you do that particular calculation by hand, what do you observe?

Comment: How do you expect any number to be strictly greater than the greatest possible number?

Comment: You should inspect the individual steps of your computation. Specifically, if the overflow happens in `(i * (i + 1))`, you wouldn't be able to detect it afterwards.

Comment: @Mat I figured that as a test I would check if it was greater that INT_MAX but still use an unsigned int. That way hopefully it would pick out a problem before the number grew to a size where it could be greater than an unsigned int.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I will attempt to figure out what value of i it happens at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 92682th triangle number is already greater than `UINT32_MAX`. But the culprit here is much earlier, in the computation of `i * (i + 1)`. There, the calculation overflows for the 65536th triangular number. If we ask Python with its native bignum support:

```
>>> 2**16 * (2**16+1) > 0xffffffff
True
```

Oops. Then if you inspect your stored numbers, you will see your sequence dropping back to low values. To attempt to emulate what the Standard says about the behaviour of this case, in Python:

```
>>> (int(2**16 * (2**16+1)) % 0xffffffff) >> 1
32768
```

and that is the value you will see for the 65536th triangular number, which is incorrect.

One way to detect overflow here is ensure that the sequence of numbers you generate is monotonic; that is, if the Nth triangle number generated is strictly greater than the (N-1)th triangle number.

To avoid overflow, you can use 64-bit variables to **both** generate & store them, or use a big number library if you need a large amount of triangle numbers.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I didn't think of simply checking that the new number was greater than the last. I changed the code and it's quitting at the right time now.

Answer (score 2):

`INT_MAX` is the maximum value of `signed int`. It's about half the maximum value of `unsigned int` (`UINT_MAX`). Your calculation of `toPush` may well get much higher than `UINT_MAX` because you square the value (if it's near `INT_MAX` the result will be much larger than `UINT_MAX` that your `toPush` can hold). In this case the `toPush` wraps around and results in smaller value than previous one.

First of all, your comparison to `INT_MAX` is flawed since your type is `unsigned int`, not `signed int`. Secondly, even a comparison to `UINT_MAX` would be incorrect since it implies that `toPush` (the left operand of the comparison expression) can hold a value above it's maximum - and that's not possible. The correct way would be to compare your generated number with the previous one. If it's lower, you know you have got an overflow and you should stop.

Additionally, you may want to use types that can hold a larger range of values (such as `unsigned long long`).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual C++ `int` (and of course `unsigned int`) is 32 bits even on 64-bit computers.

Either use `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t` to use a 64-bit value.